# PHP Google map url with odd lat lng convert in url

Tags: php, google-maps, url, curl

I have developed a script which collect lat lng from google map url.

> "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&ie=UTF8&om=1&q=24+56.7266'67+00.8324"

But when i put this url browser it converts lat lng from this-> "24+56.7266'67+00.8324" to this->  "24.945443, 67.013873" which is correct. Is their any way to get correct lat lng in php variables.

Currently I've tried this.

```
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&ie=UTF8&om=1&q=24+56.7266'67+00.8324";
$output = file_get_contents($url);
echo $output;
```

While i run my script it redirected my url like this.

> http://localhost/maps/place/24%C2%B056'43.6%22N+67%C2%B000'49.9%22E/@24.9454433,67.0138733,16z

So I've tried to get final url in variable but failed. It captures the old url not the final url after redirect.

PS: We don't want to use google map on our server. Just need correct lat lng in variables from the provided url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has resolved by below code. I didn't knew that url has containing gps data in degree,minutes,seconds.

```
function DMStoDD($deg,$min,$sec)
{
    // Converting DMS ( Degrees / minutes / seconds ) to decimal format
    return $deg+((($min*60)+($sec))/3600);
} 

    $coords = explode("'", $vars['q']);
    $lat_temp = $coords[0];
    $long_temp = $coords[1];
    $lat_decimal = explode(".", $lat_temp);
    $long_decimal = explode(".", $long_temp);
    $lat_sec = "0.".$lat_decimal[1];
    $lng_sec = "0.".$long_decimal[1];
    $lat_sec = round($lat_sec * 60,1);
    $lng_sec = round($lng_sec * 60,1);
    $lat_dd_space = explode(" ", $lat_temp);
    $lng_dd_space = explode(" ", $long_temp);
    $lat_dd = $lat_dd_space[0];
    $lng_dd = $lng_dd_space[0];
    $lat_mm = explode(".", $lat_dd_space[1]);
    $lng_mm = explode(".", $lng_dd_space[1]);
    $lat_mm = $lat_mm[0];
    $lng_mm = $lng_mm[0];
    $lat = round(DMStoDD($lat_dd,$lat_mm,$lat_sec),6);
    $long = round(DMStoDD($lng_dd,$lng_mm,$lng_sec),6);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this way google maps.

```
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&ie=UTF8&om=1&q=24+56.7266'67+00.8324";
header("Location:".$url."");
```

Comment: I want output data in variable. From@24.9454433,67.0138733

Comment: Actually i don't want to open this url. I want final redirect link data into variable.